# How can I group this data and make this calculations and drops?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this data:

```
0       1.514333e+12
1       1.514419e+12
2       1.514506e+12
3       1.514592e+12
4       1.514678e+12
            ...
1881    1.676851e+12
1882    1.676938e+12
1883    1.677024e+12
1884    1.677110e+12
1885    1.677146e+12
Name: volume1d, Length: 1886, dtype: float64
```

The data is in timeperiods, so, I need to group this data every 4 rows (every 4 hours (each row is an hour)).
for example:

```
    a b
    1 2
    1 3
    1 4
    1 4
    2 3
    2 4
    2 5
    2 4
    3 4
```

after this, I would have to add the groups.

```
a b c
1 2 2
1 3 5
1 4 9
1 4 13
2 3 3
2 4 7
2 5 12
2 4 16
3 4 4
```

to finish leaving just the las row of the groups:

```
a b c
1 4 13
2 4 16
3 4 4
```

How can I all do this?
(what I need is the last table, so if you find another way to do this, perfect)

Edited: if the last group is only contains 1,2 or 3 rows, I would like it to have those rows added.

Comment: "if the last group is only contains 1,2 or 3 rows, I would like it to have those rows added" - can you reflect that condition in your input and output ?

Comment: I don't understand your q. I dont controll the input ... its from web scrapping, and it varies

Comment: I've cited your last sentence "*Edited: if the last group is only contains 1,2 or 3 rows, I would like it to have those rows added.*" - this is your condition and your current final output (which you called "last table") does NOT reflect that, so I'm asking you to update your output according to your additional condition

Comment: Done, is it understandable now?

Comment: for the 2nd group column `c` should be `16`. Also, add tag `pandas` if it's intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) records using cumulative sum (`cumsum` function) and eventually extract the last record from each group:

```
df.assign(c=df.groupby('a').transform('cumsum')).groupby('a').last().reset_index()
```

---

```
   a  b   c
0  1  4  13
1  2  4  16
2  3  4   4
```

Comment: and how do I automatize a (I dont have a in my data)?

Comment: @javi, use columns from your `df.columns` that are equivalent to `a` and `b`

Comment: sory, my english is not very fluent. How can I make column a, I just have the data that's at the begining, it doesn't have the grups.

Comment: @javi, as you wrote "*to group this data every 4 rows*" - means that there is a column that represents values that can be grouped

Comment: sorry ... my english is not perfect ... I mean .... group 4 rows per or iow group by each four rows.

Comment: hi ... sorry ... I accepted the answer before traying ... where is b in that line?

Comment: it is implied by `pandas` as remaining column withing a group for further aggregations/transformations

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't make that line work ... I'm missing something @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: 0k, what I'm missing is that I don't know how to sum in column c only per gruop. How do I do step -2?